# Can not create trigger after insert

Tags: sql-server

I have this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Record 
ON Database 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    EXEC xp_cmdshell 'C:\test011\Program\ip camera\Source.Code\bin\Monitor.exe'
END
```

I can not run it, because I get an error:

> The specified event type(s) is/are not valid on the specified target object.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: i think sqlserver can not accept name of trigger

Comment: This smells like a huge [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) DDL triggers are very different from DML triggers. Worse is the idea that you intend to run an external application as a part of this process. I think you need to start over and concentrate on your goal and not on your current implementation path

Comment: thank for help, i create this in my application : Process.Start(@"C:\test011\Program\ipCamera\SourceCode\bin\MONITOR.exe"); it's working now